# django get parameters and pass int type

Tags: django

I have the below entry in urls.py

`url(r'^profile/(?P<price_id>[0-9]+)$', views.profile_view, name='profile'),`

Where the price_id parameter is generated by the below template snippet: 
'Proceed'

This is rendered by the below view:

```
class QuotesResultsView(ListView):
    template_name = 'pages/quotes_results.html'
    paginate_by = 20
    context_object_name = 'quotes_results'

    def get_queryset(self):
        session = self.request.session
        quotes = get_quotes(session)  # return iterable from external api
        quotes_results = quotes['searchResults']
        return quotes_results
```

When the button is clicked in the rendered template it passes (via the url to the below view):

```
def profile_view(request, price_id):
    request.session['price_id'] = int(price_id)
    ....
```

However the price_id parameter arrives in the view as a string eg '8234234' instead of an int which I have to covert. In the earlier QuotesResultsView the price_id is an int within quotes_results, but between then and it appearing in the next view its a string? Do GET parameters always get passed as strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the arguments coming from a URL are always strings, and it is your responsibility to cast them appropriately. The `get_quotes` may return a structure that contains an integer `price_id`, but it is obtaining that value through a different mechanism than the URL call.

The `price_id` in `profile_view` will always come in as a string when called by the URL configuration.